# Uniform continuity in a subinterval

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

This question is based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472061/help-to-understand-proof-to-show-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continous-in-a-cer/478012?noredirect=1#478012) answer.

I don't understand why the following must be true:

> The ϵ-goodness of $f$ on $[a,y]$ implies its ϵ-goodness on any subinterval of $[a,y]$.

This is my attempt at proving why it must be true:

> $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,y]$ means that given the $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $c,d \in [a,y]$:
>
> If $|c-d|<\delta$, then $|f(c)-f(d)|<\epsilon$.
>
> Therefore, the following must be true:
> $|a-y| < \delta$ and $|f(a)-f(y)|<\epsilon$
>
> So, if we pick any number, $x$ such that $a<x<y$, then:
>
> $|a-x|<\delta$ is true.
>
> From here, I don't know how to conclude that $|f(a)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ will be true too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. If $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,y]$, then there is a $\delta >0$ such that for any $c,d\in [a,y]$, if $|c-d|<\delta$ then $|f(c)-f(d)|<\epsilon$. Let $[p,q]$ be a subinterval of $[a,y]$. Then for any $c,d\in [p,q]$, we have $c,d\in [a,y]$, so if $|c-d|<\delta$ then $|f(c)-f(d)|<\epsilon$. This means $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[p,q]$.

Comment: where did I go wrong in my proof?